# What's the prime period of $\frac{\sin 2x + \cos 2x}{\sin 2x - \cos 2x}$

Tags: periodic-functions

What's the prime period of the following function?

$$\frac{\sin 2x + \cos 2x}{\sin 2x - \cos 2x}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin 2x+\cos 2x}{\sin 2x-\cos 2x}&=\frac{\sin 2x+\cos 2x}{\sin 2x-\cos 2x}\cdot\frac{\sin 2x+\cos 2x}{\sin 2x+\cos 2x}\\\\
&=\frac{(\sin 2x+\cos 2x)^2}{\sin^2 2x-\cos^2 2x}\\\\
&=-\frac{\sin^2 2x+2\sin 2x\cos 2x+\cos^2 2x}{\cos 4x}\\\\
&=-\frac{1+\sin 4x}{\cos 4x}\\\\
&=-\sec 4x-\tan 4x\;.
\end{align*}$$

The first term has primitive period $\dfrac{2\pi}4=\dfrac{\pi}2$, and the second has primitive period $\dfrac{\pi}4$. Can you finish it from there?

Comment: It would be $\dfrac{\pi}4$, right? could you please give me a link about how to find period of functions and what does happen to period by adding or subtracting or multiplying two functions?

Comment: @zizi: No, it would be $\pi/2$. Take a look at the graph: what you see between $-3\pi/8$ and $\pi/8$ is one full period. What happens to the period when you add or multiply two period functions can get complicated, depending on the functions and the periods; I don’t offhand know of a good online reference.

Comment: got it, thanks.